# Is it possible to have a class with constant strings that get compiled as inline code in typescript?

Tags: typescript

What I am looking for is the exact same functionality as a const enum in TypeScript but for strings. It doesn't have to be an actual type (although that would be a bonus), but what I am looking for is a way to have a large list of const strings that get compiled into the JS. The reason is that we have a large list of "magic strings" that I would like to replace with something a bit less error prone, but I don't want the overhead of having a huge list of types that aren't used on every page.

TypeScript:

```
const enum Foo {
    BarA = "BarA";
    BarB = "BarB";
}

class Test {
    myFunction = () => {
        var a = Foo.BarA;
    }
}
```

Compiled JavaScript:

```
var Test = (function () {
    function Test() {
        this.myFunction = function () {
            var a = "BarA";
        };
    }
    return Test;
})();
```

Comment: This is now supposed to be possible with [PR#9407](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/9407).

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to have a class with constant strings that get compiled as inline code in typescript

Not at the moment.

That said I would just use an object literal and let TypeScript infer the correct type :

```
var foo = {
    bar: 'bar',
    bas: 'bas'
}


var something = foo.bar; // Okay 
var somethingElse = foo.baz; // Error
```

Ofcourse you don't get inlining but *you do remove the magic nature of these strings*.